# SSL SQlAlchemy Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ssl, sqlalchemy

Python: 3.11
SQLAlchemy: '2.0.28'

I tried it for many times, to pass manual ssls but he still does not recognize my ssl and I get the exact output everytime.

```py
import ssl
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import os

ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile="vt_root.crt")
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
connect_args = {"ssl": ssl_context}
server = "SERVER"
database = "DB"
username = "USER"
password = "PW"
driver = "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server"
url = f"mssql://{username}:{password}@{server}/{database}?driver={driver}"
engine = create_engine(url, connect_args=connect_args)
connection = engine.connect()
```

What am I doing wrong? My error is

Operational `Error` :

> ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL
> Provider: [error:16000069:STORE routines::unregistered
> scheme:scheme=file][error:80000002:system library::No such file or
> directory:calling
> stat(/opt/bitnami/miniconda/envs/python3.11/ssl/certs)] (-1)
> (SQLDriverConnect)')

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is SSL certificate file is not found in the specified location.It should be in **/opt/bitnami/miniconda/envs/python3.11/ssl/certs** that location.

You can specify your certificate path. Like that

```
certificate_path = "/path/vt_root.crt"
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certificate_path)
```

I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: But I already did that, as you can see at my code? or not?